# Incorporating array into forloop // same pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, arraylist

I need some quick help on how to incorporate my array into a forloop.

I currently have a graph that takes in this as nodes:

```
var classes = [
    {"name":"test.cluster1.item1"},
    {"name":"test.cluster1.item2"},
    {"name":"test.cluster1.item3"}
];
```

I have a separate working array called fileArray which I have several nodes I would like to incorporate into my graph

```
var fileArray = ["a", "b", "c", "etc..."];
```

I'm trying to replace all the "test cluster items" in my data with every element of fileArray, how could I do this?

Currently I have this and it makes no sense, I know, but have no idea how to approach this.

```
for(i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
    var classes = [
        {"name": fileArray(i)}
    ];
}
```

Desired result:

```
var classes = [
    {"name":"fileArray[0]"},
    {"name":"fileArray[1]"},
    {"name":"fileArray[2]"},
    {"name":"fileArray[3]"},
    {"name":"fileArray[4]"}
];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the desired result for your example? Do you want `[{ name: "a" }, { name: "b" }, /*...*/]`? Do the objects in the `classes` array have properties except "name"? Are there elements in the `classes` array, which are not "test cluster items", aka should stay in the result array?

Comment: Added the desire result, no, name is the only property. @ASDFGerte

Comment: will it be `"fileArray(0)"` or the content of `fileArray[0]]` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit fileArray[0], sorry typo.

Comment: `classes = classes.map((_, i) => ({ name: fileArray[i] }));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version using `forEach`. Use `reduce` and make deep copies of each object's property if you would like a new array, otherwise it makes sense to do it in place on the current `classes` array which maintains any other keys the objects may have:

```js
var classes = [
    {"name":"test.cluster1.item1"},
    {"name":"test.cluster1.item2"},
    {"name":"test.cluster1.item3"}
];

var fileArray = ["a", "b", "c", "etc..."];

classes.forEach((e, i) => e.name = fileArray[i]);

console.log(classes);
```

Comment: Both of these only creates 3 name nodes in the classes array. My fileArray array is a lot longer and is dynamic, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: They "replace" - the classes array only has three elements, so it only outputs three aswell. At least that's how i understood it, and likely why the code in this answer is as it is.

Comment: @Akshay Can you clarify what you want? It seemed to me that `classes` and `fileArray` would be the same length and you want them to merge in parallel, right? Otherwise, why bother with `classes` at all? It'd just be `fileArray.map((e) => {return {name: e};});`

Comment: I want my classes array to match the number of elements in my fileArray. However, I do not know how many elements I have in the fileArray because it is dynamic, I only added 3 names in the class array in my question as an example.

Comment: See my edit. Why do you need `classes` at all? You're discarding all of the information from it and the length doesn't matter, so just map each element in the `fileArray` to an object with a `name` property.

Comment: yeah I got the edit thanks. I have no idea why i didn't just think of that.